# express multer Cannot read property 'profileimage' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am trying to submit a form which has a file input within it with a name of `profileimage`, i am using express 4, express generator and multer.

In my `app.js` I added multer like so:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
```

The tutorial i am following actually sets up multer like so (after requiring it) but it gives me an error:

```
app.use(multer({dest: './uploads'}));
```

And in my `routes` folder inside the respective file I have the following:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
// get form values
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
var password2 = req.body.password2;

// check for image field
if (req.files.profileimage)
{
    console.log('Uploading file...');
...
```

However when I submit the form I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'profileimage' of undefined
```

It seems to not be able to understand `req.files.profileimage`, but I don't know why?

Comment: does your request body has a single file or multiple files?

Comment: just one file input type if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API for `multer` changed a bit some time ago, so some tutorials out there still use the old API.

For a single file, you would do something like:

```
var uploads = multer({dest: './uploads'});

// ...

router.post('/register', uploads.single('profileimg'), function(req, res, next) {

   // ...

   if (req.file) {
     console.log('Profile image uploaded');
   }
});
```

See the [`multer` documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/ea26455052f927101766d627dc67d846d0908141/README.md) for more examples of other scenarios.

Comment: I tried something similar but it didn't work out. Where does it all go? As I said i am using express generator for the website setup, so I included multer and var uploads = multer({dest: './uploads'}); in the app.js file. I also tried including them inside my routes file (the respective file inside the  routes folder) and doing what you suggested but then I get `TypeError: uploads.single is not a function`

Comment: and if i dont include multer inside the routes file then it gives another error saying `ReferenceError: multer is not defined` (even though it IS included in the app.js file). But as I said I did include it in the routes file but then I got the above error.

Comment: What version of `multer` do you have installed? Maybe it is outdated.

Comment: Yea I did mess around with other versions, I required multer inside the routes file instead of app.js (which seems ridiculous but I guess it has to be so now), and it seems to be working, thanks!

Comment: Had the same problem and this fixed the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (req.files && req.files.profileImage) {
// only if there are files
} else {
 // You should see this now
}
```